# Could the graviton be more than one particle?

Tags: gravity, quantum-gravity, theory-of-everything, emergent-properties

I guess this amounts to saying that gravity isn't a fundamental force and is, in fact, an emergent phenomenon (as in Erik Verlinde's theory). If gravity can be 'unified' with the other forces surely it has to be explained in terms of some connection with the electroweak interaction and the strong force as well. Therefore there should be some action on the part of W and Z bosons and perhaps some other particle(s), the Higgs possibly(?). If not, surely it's actually a totally separate force and not 'unifiable' with the other forces.

The question I'm trying to ask results in part from my confusion with what are strictly 'quantum gravity' theories and 'theories of everything'? As I understand (or understood) these theories, I thought that they were part of the same endeavour, is this right? And could gravity in fact still be considered fundamental if more than one particle were involved in it?

Sorry for more than one question within the same question, but they're so closely-related that I thought it'd be counterproductive to ask them in different posts.

Comment: The main challenge to a composite graviton model is its being massless. Massive graviton models have been attempted (though they run into problems of their own), but I don't think even they use composite gravitons.

Comment: Composite (and/or more than one) massless spin-2 particles are forbidden/severely restricted by [Weinberg-Witten soft theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg%E2%80%93Witten_theorem).